# An exercise about generalization of Legendre symbol

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, solution-verification, algebraic-number-theory

Sorry, my question was a duplicate, and I found this question and its answer on math stack exchange, and everything is done: [Generalization of the legendre symbol](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193603/generalization-of-the-legendre-symbol)

I want to solve and realize two consecutive exercises from Cox. The 2nd exercise is very easy I proved it completely, but I have some difficulties with some parts of the first exercise. Here you can see the first exercise:

Assume that the number field $K$ contains a primitive $n$-th root of unity $\zeta$. In this problem we will discuss a generalization of the Legendre symbol. Let $a \in \mathcal{O}_K$ and let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$ such that $na \notin \mathfrak{p}$.

(a) Prove that $1, \zeta, \cdots, \zeta^{n-1}$ are distinct modulo $\mathfrak{p}$. Hint: show that $x^n — 1$ is separable modulo $\mathfrak{p}$.

(b) Use (a) to prove that $n|N(\mathfrak{p})-1$.

(c) Show that $a^{(N(\mathfrak{p})-1)/n}$ is congruent to a unique $n$-th root of unity modulo $\mathfrak{p}$.
This allows us to define the nth power Legendre symbol $(\frac{a}{\mathfrak{p}})_n$ to be the
unique nth root of unity such that
$$a^{(N(\mathfrak{p})-1)/n} \equiv (\frac{a}{\mathfrak{p}})_n (\mod \mathfrak{p}).$$

(d) Prove that $(\frac{a}{\mathfrak{p}})_n = 1$ if and only if $a$ is an $n$-th power residue modulo $\mathfrak{p}$.

---

> **I have no idea to prove part (b)**.

> Is "the following proof for part (c)" true? I think I completed my proof for this part while I was typing my question in this site! Is it true?

My attempts: I proved the parts (a) and (d), also I think I am almost very close to proving part (c), I mean I am doing something but I have some misunderstandings and doubts, and here is my "proof":

"Proof" of part (c): Part $b$ implies that $(N(\mathfrak{p})-1)/n$ is a natural number and set $A:=a^{(N(\mathfrak{p})-1)/n}$. Also the residue field $\frac{\mathcal{O}_K}{\mathfrak{p}}$ is a field of order $N(\mathfrak{p})$, and its multiplicative group is a cyclic group of order $N(\mathfrak{p})-1$, so we can conclude that $A^n=a^{(N(\mathfrak{p})-1)}=1$ in the residue field, hence $A=a^{(N(\mathfrak{p})-1)/n}$ is a root of $X^n-1=0$. Also I "guess" that the equation $X^n-1$ has exactly $n$ roots in the residue field (**why this should be true? I can't prove it**), and by part (a), $1, \zeta, \cdots, \zeta^{n-1}$ are different roots and all roots of this equation. So $A=a^{(N(\mathfrak{p})-1)/n}$ should be one of these roots of unities, and the uniqueness follows from the distinctness in part (a).

Now, exactly during typing my question in MathStackExchange, I think I found a proof for the bold sentence. The multiplicative group is **cyclic**, and I realized that we can obtain a more general statement:

Let $d$ be a divisor of the order of the multiplicative group, I mean a divisor of $N(\mathfrak{p})-1$. Then it is very obvious that the equation $X^d-1=0$ has exactly $d$ solutions. (Just consider a generator $g$ of this **cyclic** group, and consider all powers and check all of them)